# What version of fabric-composer npm packages to use for applications targeted on Fabric v.6?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a fabric-composer application that will be deployed on Fabric v0.6.      When I look at the packages.json files inside of the .bna files for existing sample applications I see the following:

```
  "devDependencies": {
...,
"composer-admin": "latest",
"composer-cli": "latest",
"composer-client": "latest",
"composer-connector-embedded": "latest",
...
}
```

My question is,  is it appropriate to use "latest" as the version for the composer-* dependencies or should I specify an older version of admin, cli, client and connector-embedded packages?  I know that there have been a lot of changes going on in fabric-composer for the Fabric v1.0 so wondering if latest versions are backward compatible or if I need to stay at an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions are backwards compatible and can be used with both HLF v0.6 and HLF v1.